# Exclude questions with ignored tag in subscribed tag email

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, subscription

I'm subscribed to a tag. But I also ignore a tag. The two are sometimes used together, and I don't want to get the question(s) with the tag I ignore to my mail box in that case.

Please exclude those questions from the mail, and if this cause no questions to match, don't send any mail.

Comment: I was about to edit before reopening, but noticed something weird. Suppose there are 10 questions in the subscribed tag email, and in 2 of them an ignored tag is used. You don't want to get the email at all, or do you mean you want the email, just without those two questions? That's a very big difference.

Comment: If there are 10 questions with that tag within 15 minutes (which never happens with the one I'm following) and 2 of those have my ignored tag, I want a mail with the remaining 8. Of course, otherwise it would hide questions from me that I want to see. And if after that filtering no questions are left, of course I do not want a mail saying "0 new questions".

Comment: Cheers, edited.